# Excel: find a word in a cell, then return the preceding word and the found word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a slightly different take on a previous question I asked. I tried to modify the great advice I received but couldn't quite get there.

I am looking to find text in a cell (not case specific), then return the preceding word plus the found text. I prefer a formulaic solution (over a macro).

Sample cell contents include the following where I'm looking for "**TRUCK**":

"This is a test **dump TRUCK** like it 54" - I want "**dump TRUCK**"

"This is **pick-up Truck** forgot 346 I like" - I want "**pick-up Truck**"

I tried some combo of the Mid() function but wasn't quite getting it:

```
=MID(B2,(FIND("Truck",B2,1)-1),FIND(" ",B2,FIND("Truck",B2,1)-1)-FIND("Truck",B2,1)+1)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `FIND` is case sensitive, but you can use `SEARCH` instead

Comment: This would be much easier with some of the RegEx Google Sheets functions like [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) or VBA UDF if that is an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" Truck ",B2)+5)," ",REPT(" ",99)),199))
```

---

`LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" Truck ",B2)+5)` gets the "`This is a test dump TRUCK`" part.

Then `SUBSTITUTE( ^ ," ",REPT(" ",99))` gets:

```
This                                                                                                   is                                                                                                   a                                                                                                   test                                                                                                   dump                                                                                                   TRUCK
```

and `=TRIM(RIGHT( ^ ,199))` gets the last 2 words from the above and removes the extra spaces.

Comment: Nice exercise (y)... but let us notify the OP that restricting the solution to formula was a bit like programming a Website in assembly language :P

Comment: @A.S.H this seemed like an easy formula to me, otherwise I would be too lazy to answer it :]

Comment: One the idea "flashes", it becomes somehow "easy" for an experienced developer like you, I understand that. I only wanted to remind (the average reader, not you) that the formula language of Excel is designed for basic things, it's not a programming language and should not be used abusively to escape from learning VBA ;)

Comment: I remember the days where websites were written with a text editor and an image program!! (did coders have more / better / different skills??? What is good about this solution is that it shows that logic and simple steps can do things. It all depends on how many items need to be tested.

Comment: Awesome guys. That worked very well. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @A.S.H As a side note, I am not sure if Excel Formulas would be allowed on SO if they were not considered related to programming. You might find this talk interesting [GOTO 2016 • Pure Functional Programming in Excel • Felienne Hermans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yKf8TrLUOw)

Comment: @Slai ah, I never said they were not related to programming! To the contrary I consider them as an amazing task and moreover, we should remember that VBA is not always an option (for security reason). I wish that  Excel's formula language be pushed ahead to become a "complete" functional language. And I must admit again, that your formula solution just i.m.p.r.e.s.s.e.d. me :)

Comment: @SolarMike Of course I remember the days where web pages were made with **notepad**. That's why I never made it into the web page programming business :P